# How to run schema:load on the initial capistrano 3 deploy of my rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, capistrano3

I would like to run `db:schema:load` in place of `db:migrate` on the initial deploy of my rails app.

This used to be fairly trivial, as seen [in this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329778/dbschemaload-vs-dbmigrate-with-capistrano), but in Capistrano 3, they have deprecated the `deploy:cold` task. The initial deploy isn't any different than all subsequent deploys.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I, too, am new to Capistrano, and trying to use it for the first time to deploy a Rails app to production servers I configured with Puppet.

I finally had to dig into the Capistrano source (and capistrano/bundler, and capistrano/rails, and even sshkit and net-ssh to debug auth problems) to determine exactly how everything works before I felt confidant deciding for myself what changes I wanted to make.  I just finished making those changes, and I'm pleased with the results:

```
# lib/capistrano/tasks/cold.rake
namespace :deploy do

  desc "deploy app for the first time (expects pre-created but empty DB)"
  task :cold do
    before 'deploy:migrate', 'deploy:initdb'
    invoke 'deploy'
  end

  desc "initialize a brand-new database (db:schema:load, db:seed)"
  task :initdb do
    on primary :web do |host|
      within release_path do
        if test(:psql, 'portal_production -c "SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema=\'public\' AND table_type=\'BASE TABLE\';"|grep schema_migrations')
          puts '*** THE PRODUCTION DATABASE IS ALREADY INITIALIZED, YOU IDIOT! ***'
        else
          execute :rake, 'db:schema:load'
          execute :rake, 'db:seed'
        end
      end
    end
  end

end
```

The deploy:cold task merely hooks my custom deploy:inidb task to run before deploy:migrate.  That way the schema and seeds get loaded, and the deploy:migrate step that follows does nothing (safely) because there are no new migrations to run.  As a safety, I test to see if the schema_migrations table already exists before loading the schema in case you run deploy:cold again.

Note: I choose to create the DB using Puppet so I can avoid having to grant the CREATEDB privilege to my production postgresql user, but if you want Capistrano to do it, just add "execute :rake, 'db:create'" before the db:schema:load, or replace all three lines with 'db:setup'.

Comment: I don't know why they removed deploy:cold in Capistrano 3 - it still seems like the right approach to me. But I'm glad it pushed me into making my own version custom to my needs, and I'm glad I now understand the inner workings of the system as well as I do.

Comment: What is 'portal_production'?

Comment: The name of my production database.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to define `deploy:cold` as basically a duplicate of the normal deploy task but with `deploy:db_load_schema` instead of `deploy:migrations`.  For example:

```
desc 'Deploy app for first time'
task :cold do
  invoke 'deploy:starting'
  invoke 'deploy:started'
  invoke 'deploy:updating'
  invoke 'bundler:install'
  invoke 'deploy:db_load_schema' # This replaces deploy:migrations
  invoke 'deploy:compile_assets'
  invoke 'deploy:normalize_assets'
  invoke 'deploy:publishing'
  invoke 'deploy:published'
  invoke 'deploy:finishing'
  invoke 'deploy:finished'
end

desc 'Setup database'
task :db_load_schema do
  on roles(:db) do
    within release_path do
      with rails_env: (fetch(:rails_env) || fetch(:stage)) do
        execute :rake, 'db:schema:load'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

It might even be better to run the `deploy:db_schema_load` task independently, as the tasks included in the default `deploy` might change over time.

I actually using `db:setup` for fresh deploys because it seeds the database after creating tables:

```
desc 'Setup database'
task :db_setup do
  ...
        execute :rake, 'db:setup'
  ...
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion; it made me more comfortable with my own instinct that recreating deploy:cold was the way to go. I posted my own version below yours.